# I'm confused by all the different ways to modify a noun. How do I know when to use what?

Tags: adjectives, onomatopoeia, na-adjectives, modification

1. 意味不明,学校全体,現実可能
2. 安定した収入
3. もやもやとした記憶、もやもやしていた気持ち

(1) I keep coming across examples like this where a na-adjective is placed after the noun and with the な omitted.

Why is the order reversed in these instances and can this be applied to all na-adjectives?

(2) Why is する being used to modify one noun with the other here and not な or の?

(3) I'm aware that words like もやもや are onomatopoeic and can use とする. But I'm confused why sometimes it uses と and sometimes it doesn't. And also why sometimes it's した and other times していた. Is there any difference in meaning or is it just a matter of whatever you feel like saying?

Also, I get the feeling this question has probably already been asked in some form or other already but I had no luck finding anything. I'm new here so any tips on how to find related questions would be appreciated as well.

Comment: `現実可能` -- 「実現可能」じゃなく？